# Any workaround to call a function if the element is in a TD tag?

Tags: javascript, html-table, onchange

sample code:

```
HTML:
    <td title="" class="fv fvu" id="custompicklist1" style="padding-left: 6px; cursor:     default;">&nbsp;</td>


Javascript:
    <script>
    function InactivateConvert() {

        var bu = (document).getElementById("A0.R0.Indexed Pick 3").innerHTML,
            kob = (document).getElementById("A0.R0.ZOptimizedCustomPick_0").innerHTML,
            ebd = (document).getElementById("A0.R0.Estimated Close Date").innerHTML,
            er = (document).getElementById("A0.R0.Potential Revenue").innerHTML;

        if (bu !== "&nbsp;" && kob !== "&nbsp;"  && ebd !== "&nbsp;"  && er !== "&nbsp;" ) {
$("#BTN_TB_LeadDetailForm_ConvertLead").addClass("buttonTD");
        }
        else {
            $("#BTN_TB_LeadDetailForm_ConvertLead").removeClass("buttonTD").addClass("disableButtonTD").attr('title', "Please make sure that the following fields are dropdown1, dropdown2, date3, are filled in");
        }
    }
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#DIV_SC_InlinePLEditor:select").attr("onchange","InactivateConvert()");
InactivateConvert();
});
</script>
```

whenever a certain field is populated by user, i would like to call a function to enable a button through an onChange() event. say for example, I am trying to monitor if the custompicklist1 is updated. so once updated, the onChange() event is invoked and call a certain function that will enable a button.

so its like a validation for a field that should be filled up before a button is enabled.

the thing is, the TD tag does not support onChange.

I hope this make sense.

pardon me, am a newbie here. thank you for your very quick feedback! :)

anyone knows how to accomplish this please? thanks in advance!

> my problem is, the button "#BTN_TB_LeadDetailForm_ConvertLead", won't enable/disable until i manually refresh the page. we would want it to automatically react accordingly as soon as the field is updated.

Comment: Could you re-word your explaination? It's hard to understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: Where's your code that populates it? That would seem to be the right place to put code to enable your button.

Comment: Did you try enabling the button in a handler function for the onchange event of element ? This should help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onchange

Answer (score 0):

A change to the content of a `td` doesn't fire `onchange` event. You need to use [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to detect changes in a `td`. A simple example:

```js
function firesOnTDChange(m) {
  alert(m[0].type);
}
var td = document.getElementById('custompicklist1'),
  tdObserver = new MutationObserver(firesOnTDChange);

tdObserver.observe(td, {
  childList: true
});

setTimeout(function() {
  td.innerHTML = 'Row 1 Col 2';
}, 2000);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1 Col1</td>
    <td id="custompicklist1">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Notice, that Mutation Observers are not supported in IE<11.